# Xamarin Unhandled Exception can't load MainActivity from assembly

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I wanted to try making some `android` apps with `Xamarin`, but for some reason i just can't get around this error:

Unhandled Exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'LønCalc.MainActivity'
>   from assembly 'LønCalc, Version=1.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. occurred

This is a fresh project and i haven't touched any of the code and in the past i could definitely launch any project with the default auto-generated code without issues.

I have an older project from about 4 months ago and that one can launch with no problems, and i created this project the same way, so i'm not sure why it can't load the `MainActivity` from the project assembly...Maybe there is some initial setup i missed, i'm a bit of a newbie.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so i managed to find the solution, and it is super simple. Somehow the danish letter "Ø" in "LønCalc" was causing the exception. I made the exact same App but renamed it "SalaryCalc" and now i can run the app no problem.

Comment: Hi i am getting the same issue could u please help me by describing the solution with some more detail